# How to centralize <f:convertDateTime> timezone in JSF?

Tags: datetime, jsf, timezone, converters

I am using the following JSF converter for my date inputs.

```
<f:convertDateTime dateStyle="medium" timeZone="EST" type="date" />
```

I want to centralize the converter so that I can change the timezone or the datestyle in one place. How is that possible?

Can I override the `<f:convertDateTime>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way is relying on system default timezone (instead of UTC as internally used by JSF). So, if you have 100% control over the production runtime environment and the production system platform timezone is EST, then just add the following context parameter to `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way JSF will use the system platform timezone as obtained by [`TimeZone#getDefault()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) as converter's default timezone instead of UTC.

If you have no control over it, then your best bet is to create an application scoped bean holding that property and reference it instead:

```html
<f:convertDateTime ... timeZone="#{app.timeZone}" />
```

You *can* extend the [`DateTimeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html) class behind `<f:convertDateTime>` as follows in order to get a converter with all properties already set, but you would not be able to declare additional attributes from the view side on without wrapping it in a custom tag (which requires a `TagHandler` and some XML boilerplate):

```
@FacesConverter("defaultDateConverter")
public class DefaultDateConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    public DefaultDateConverter() {
        setDateStyle("medium");
        setType("date");
        setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    }

}
```

Use it as `<f:converter converterId="defaultDateConverter" />`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I also add the datestyle to web.xml?